# How to calculate probabilities of events with infinite sample space?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the following game,

> Albert and Bob play a game with a bag containing 3 red marbles and 1 white marble. Albert is intentionally decided to do the odd numbered turns and the even numbered turns for Bob. In each turn, a player takes a marble (at random), if it is white,  the player wins, the game is over. Otherwise, the taken marble is return to the bag and let the next player does his/her turn. What is the probability that Bob wins?

## Attempt

I cannot solve this because it seems to me the sample space is infinity. Why?
Because there is a chance both players just take red balls in a very long sequence of turns as follows:

- $\{r,r,r,r,r,r,\cdots\}$

What is the hint to solve this problem?

Comment: Geometric distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two options to solve this question.

**Option 1** The probability of winning is $p=0.25$. The probability of winning at stage $k$ is $(1-p)^{k-1}p$ (nobody won at the previous stages times the probability of winning in this stage). So the probability of winning on an odd stage is
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^{2k-1}p$$
which is a well known geometric series.

**Option 2** Let $O$ be the event that the game is won on an odd round, and let $E$ be the event that the game is one on the first round. Conditioning on $E$, we get $\Pr(O)=\Pr(O\vert E) \Pr(E)+\Pr(O \vert \bar{E})\Pr(\bar{E})$.
Clearly, $\Pr(O\vert E)=1$ and $\Pr(E)=0.25=1-\Pr(\bar{E})$.

Now, if the game wasn't won on the first round, than from now on the game is "restarted" with the players switching roles. An odd round in the restared game is an even round in the original game. For example, the first round in the resstarted game is actually the second round of the original game. Hence, $\Pr(O \vert \bar{E})=1-\Pr(O)$. The result is an equation
$$\Pr(O)=0.25+0.75(1-\Pr(O))$$
which can be solved to find $\Pr(O)$.

Comment: Second method is quite useful. +1!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**  Probability for Bob winning in

- 2 moves : $\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$
- 4 moves : $\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$
- 6 moves : $(\frac{3}{4})^{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$

and so on.

Do you notice any pattern?